# User redirection not working with GoDaddy domain

Tags: dns, godaddy, domain-transfer

I have a server (say server.js) which (at some point) should redirect the user to facebook.com like so:

`sub.domain.com/auth/with/facebook` => `facebook.com/API/authorize/..`

The problem I am facing is that whenever I request url: `sub.domain.com/auth/with/facebook` I get a white page, nothing more.

What makes me suspect that it is GoDaddy is that when I invoke the IP address of my vps like so:

```
x1.x5x.x8.8:3000/auth/with/facebook
```

the redirection works well, I land on `facebook.com/API/authorize/..` with the expected content.

*Note: I purchased the domain name at GoDaddy and the VPS at OVH and in my GoDaddy redirection panel `sub.domain.com 301 redirection to x1.x5x.x8.8:3000`*

Comment: By GoDaddy "redirection panel", do you their domain "Forwarding and Masking"? If so, I don't think you can forward to different port numbers, even though it lets you add it (at least when I tested it).  Since it appears you're redirecting requests to your VPS's IP address on port 3000 to `facebook.com`, are you also redirecting requests to the subdomain as well? Seems like you should just do the redirection in your VPS's webserver and not try to use GoDaddy for that.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I directly use my VPS domain. Everything works fine.